# How create and delete dynamically tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin.forms chat app, How to achieve this task. 
Attached screenshot 3 group available and after click respected chat is activated and bind, this group bind dynamically. Its would be 20 or more than 20. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XamarinForms-MVVM-Custom-dfc146ee

In this article we can create our own tabs so, we can add or delete the items dynamically need to change RibbonOptions ItemsSource.

Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Where is INavigableTabBuilder coming from?